# difference between Load DLL and Direct Call

Tags: c++

For example, I want use Windows API like  GetWindowsDirectory`` , `GetSystemInfo` and etc... I can use the API directly or calling through `GetProcAddress`:

**Method 1**
Here I can calling APIs with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`:

```
#include <windows.h>

typedef UINT (WINAPI *GET_WIN_DIR)(LPWSTR lpBuffer, UINT size);

TCHAR infoBuffer[MAX_PATH + 1];
HINSTANSE dllLoad = LoadLibrary("Kernel32.dll");
GET_WIN_DIR function = (GET_WIN_DIR )GetProcAddress(dllLoad, "GetWindowsDirectoryW");

int result = function2(infoBuffer, MAX_PATH + 1);
```

**Method 2**
Here I can calling directly APIs like `GetWindowsDirectory`:

```
#include <windows.h>

TCHAR infoBuffer[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetWindowsDirectory(infoBuffer, MAX_PATH);
```

1. What is the difference between the two methods above?
2. Is it load Library impact on executable file?(.exe) (I did test, but it's not changed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Microsoft calls

- **Method 1** ... Explicit linking
- **Method 2** ... Implicit linking

From MSDN [Linking an Executable to a DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx):

> Implicit linking is sometimes referred to as static load or load-time dynamic linking. Explicit linking is sometimes referred to as dynamic load or run-time dynamic linking.
>
> With implicit linking, the executable using the DLL links to an import library (.lib file) provided by the maker of the DLL. The operating system loads the DLL when the executable using it is loaded. The client executable calls the DLL's exported functions just as if the functions were contained within the executable.
>
> With explicit linking, the executable using the DLL must make function calls to explicitly load and unload the DLL and to access the DLL's exported functions. The client executable must call the exported functions through a function pointer.
>
> An executable can use the same DLL with either linking method. Furthermore, these mechanisms are not mutually exclusive, as one executable can implicitly link to a DLL and another can attach to it explicitly.

In our projects we use implicit linking in any common case.

We use the explicit linking exceptionally in two situations:

1. for plug-in DLLs which are loaded explicitly at run-time
2. in special cases where the implicit linked function is not the right one.

The 2<sup>nd</sup> case may happen if we use DLLs which themselves link to distinct versions of other DLLs (e.g. from Microsoft). This is, of course, a bit critical. Actually, we try to prevent the 2<sup>nd</sup> case.

Comment: _Actually, we try to prevent the 2nd case_  Yes, I bet you do.  Do you have a specific example to hand? - I'm curious.  Is this a Qt thing?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes. Before we switched to Qt, we used GTK+/gtkmm on Windows. If I got this right, the GTK+ DLL was linked against a different MS runtime DLL. I realized this effectively when I tried to change the locale - there was no effect for GTK+. A collaborator fixed this by loading the address of the correct function and fixed (better: worked around) the issue. On one hand I was happy about the fix but "competing" versions of the "same" DLL felt somehow bad. (And yes, I'm aware that especially mixing VS DLLs is best chance to shoot in your own foot.)

Comment: OK, thanks.  I thought it might be something like that.  As you say, not a great situation to be in generally.

Answer (score 6):

The main purpose of what @Scheff calls 'explicit linking' is twofold:

1. If you're not sure whether the the DLL you want to use to is going to be present on the machine at runtime (although you can also use [/DELAYLOAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/linker-support-for-delay-loaded-dlls) for this which is a lot more convenient).
2. If you're not sure if the *function* you want to call is present in (for example) all versions of Windows on which you want your application to run.

Regarding point 1, an example of this might be reading or writing WMA files.  Some older versions of Windows did not include WMA support by default (we're going back quite a long way here) and if you implicitly link to WMA.DLL then your application won't start up if it's not present.  Using explicit linking (or /DELAYLOAD) lets you check for this at runtime and put up a polite message if it's missing while still allowing the rest of your app to function as normal.

As for point 2, you might, for example, want to make use of the [`LoadIconWithScaleDown()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775703.aspx) function because it generally produces a nicer scaled icon than [`LoadIcon()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072.aspx).  However, if you just blindly call it then, again, your app wont run on XP because XP doesn't support it, so you would instead call it conditionally, via `GetProcAddress()`, if it's available and fall back to `LoadIcon()` if not.

Okay, so to round off, what's the deal with /DELAYLOAD?  Well, this is a [linker switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/specifying-dlls-to-delay-load) that lets you tell the linker which DLL's are optional for your app.  Once you've done that, then you can do something like this:

```
if (LoadIconWithScaleDown)
    LoadIconWithScaleDown (...);
else
    LoadIcon (...);
```

And that is pretty neat.

So I hope you can now see that this question is really about the *utility* of explicit linking versus the inconvenience involved (all of which goes away anyway with /DELAYLOAD).  What goes on under the covers is, for me, less interesting.

And yes, the end result, in terms of the way the program behaves, is the same.  Explicit linking or delay loading might involve a small (read: tiny) performance overhead but I really wouldn't worry about that, and delay loading involves a few potential 'gotchas' (which won't affect most normal mortals) as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/constraints-of-delay-loading-dlls).

Comment: This is a nice add-on to that what I've quoted from MS. I've to admit that we settle very less directly on the win32 API but try to stay portable using `std`, `Qt` and other portable libraries. Hence, issues like described by you occur rarely on our side. In one of these rare cases, (when I once wrote a portability wrapper on my own), I realized that the win32 functions I planned to use are marked with a "Windows version stamp". In our case, I just memorized this as remark for the minimum requirement (and actually it didn't change). Possible only, as we don't develop for consumers... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks, much appreciated.  If / when you do need to descend to 'raw' Win32 for whatever reason, then MSDN always documents the minimum Windows version that supports the particular API you happen to be looking at (you can compare and contrast the two links I give above to see what I mean - it's always at the bottom of the page).  It's fashionable to slate Microsoft's technical documentation but, with the odd exception, it's not too shabby.

Comment: @PaulSanders very very tanks, very nice

Comment: @PaulSanders Have no ideas about question 2? and how can I cut down executable size? i changed flag related visual Studio but I want Shrink it a lot, I heard for this can 1. use explicit linking 2. delete extra section in PE file

Comment: @Mr.DeveloperCplus Are you using Visual Studio (the Community Edition is fine)? Compile as a Release build (makes a big difference) and link with the dynamic run time library rather than the static one (although dynamic is the default), that's the best you can do.  The compiler and linker will eliminate any dead code, especially if you enable 'full program optimisation' in Visual Studio (which again is the default in Release builds).

Comment: @PaulSanders  yes, i use visual studio, ok, i do, tanks a lot