# Linking dynamic library with cmake on windows

Tags: c++, dll, cmake

My understanding for linking dll's on windows is the library does not need to be present during compilation/linking. From reading up a bit it seems this is not the case on linux. Anyway I am trying to build an application on windows that will use a dynamic library at run time.

I add the library path and then link the libraries. This works and compiles but I want to build on the pipeline where the libraries aren't present. My understanding for dll's was they are not required during build stage. If I comment out the `link_libraries` it doesn't compile.

```sh
  link_directories(${HOME}/lib/${TARGET})
  if("${ENVIRONMENT}" STREQUAL "WINDOWS")
    link_libraries(mylib1.dll mylib2.dll mylib3.dll)
```

Comment: _My understanding for dll's was they are not required during build stage._ For the exported symbols of a DLL, there might be a corresponding .lib file which is used to link against. To allow this, dependencies have to be setup properly in CMake although the DLL itself is not considered in linking. (The topic of project dependencies, I leave aside...)

Comment: @Scheff So this means the .lib is still required at the linking stage when dynamically  linking

Comment: Yepp. When DLLs are built, an accompying lib file (for import of exported symbols) is built as well. (Don't confuse this with a lib for static build. It's, of course, much smaller than the corresponding static lib would be.) The exception would be if you load DLL at runtime in your code directly (say for a plug-in).

Comment: I once picked up a bit stuff about DLLs from MSDN: [SO: difference between Load DLL and Direct Call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50894337/7478597) which might be of help...

Comment: You can include libraries with CMake commands `find_library` `include_directory` and `target_link_libraries`, which is mostly platform independent. Normally, you wouldn't link against .so files or .dll files directly because it breaks platform-independence.